# C : Connect a oriented graph knowing only vertexes and outgoing edges

Tags: c, graph, dijkstra, adjacency-list

Having a text file with all the vertexes (stations) and their outgoing edges (trains), each one with an arrival time and a departure time, which is the best way to implement an oriented graph knowing that may be thousands of vertexes and that the only way to know the adjacent station is  to check for the arrival time of the train in another station that is the closest greater to the departure time of the previous station?  I need to build a data structure that would let me find the single source shortest path.

Comment: What have you sketched out already?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: There's no way "how do I implement a connection planner" is appropriate in scope for SO.

Comment: to create a list for every train with the stations it goes by, and then sort this to find the schedule for every train, after this i can build an adjacency list of the stations by adding for every train the station it goes to to the adjacency list of the station it come from. The fact is that i feel im missing some clever solution and like i described would need a lot of time to calculate the faster path from a station to another.

Comment: @millimoose sorry my english isn't good, tell me a good title and i change it

Comment: This is not a problem with the title of your question, but with its *scope*. You're not asking us to resolve a problem while implementing whatever you're doing, it seems you're asking someone for a whole implementation of that thing.

Comment: I just looking for suggestions about the data structure to use, i have read about adjacency lists, hash tables or even binary trees but i can't choose which one suits best for this problem.

Comment: Well, the abstract data structure is clearly a graph. Which specific implementation you should use depends on what basic operations you need to do on the graph in your algorithm. Which you don't seem to have, so that's where you should start.

Comment: The main problem here is that I *think* that to implement a connection planner, the costs of the given vertices change over time. (I.e. based on the start time and the route already taken.) This is why it's very unlikely you'll get some sort of well-known recipe as an answer. As I said before, you've given a broad specification of a complex problem. "Here's what I have to do, any thoughts?" usually isn't a great SO question - you should ideally at least get to the point where you know what you need help with, instead of making wild guesses like your data structure comment.

Comment: Now, if you have the coordinates of the stations, you could maybe do an A* search by using the euclidean distance as the heuristic. Or, obviously, some other admissible ("optimistic") heuristic for the remaining travel time. The best travel time ignoring train connections and waiting would work, but you'd have to compute that for every intermediate stop which might not be feasible. And I'll admit this is an educated guess. Where "educated" is literal in that I might be throwing random words I remember from Algorithms 101 around.